# Creating dynamic data validation

Tags: google-sheets-formula

Given the following dataset in one sheet, let's say 'Product Types' (columns and headers displayed):
| A            | B        | C       |
| :----------: | :------: | :-----: |
| Product Type | Desktops | Laptops |
| Desktops     | Dell     | Dell    |
| Laptops      | HP       | Apple   |

In another sheet, let's say 'Assets', I've set column A to require a match to the data validation of an item listed in column A of 'Product Types' (not including the header). What I'm trying to do is that once column A is selected in 'Assets', I'd like to create a dynamic query data validation that will then present the values of the column with the header in 'Product Types'.

As an example, in the 'Assets' sheet, if column A has "Laptops" selected, column B will use data validation for values under the "Laptops" column in 'Product Types'; then giving the only options as "Dell" or "Apple". Alternatively, if ColA is changed to "Desktops", data validation is defined to only allow "Dell" or "HP" as options.

I'm unsure if this is possible. However, data validation in Google Sheets claims to allow a range or "formula".

I don't remember where I sourced this formula from, but it can present the values I need when running the query within a cell. However, I'm unable to use the same formula within a data validation field.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2, TRANSPOSE({'Product Types'!A1:M1; 
 REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(QUERY(IF('Product Types'!A2:M<>"", 'Product Types'!A2:M&",", )
 ,,999^99)), ",$", )}), 2, 0)))
```

The above query presents the correct comma-separated values of the column I want in 'Product Types', but I'm not sure if this can be translated into something data validation can use or if there's altogether a different method to accomplish this.

P.S. I'm new. Markdown for the table seems to work when editing, but not when published..

Comment: When you use a formula as data validation, you return TRUE/FALSE depending on the input being valid or not. You can't return a list and expect this to populate the dropdown dynamically. The only option to create the dropdown (data validation) dynamically is through app script.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is no. data validation does not support direct input of complex formulae. you will need to run your formula in some column and then reference the range of that column within the data validation